# Asp javascript send parameters and object ModalDialog

Tags: javascript, showmodaldialog

In one asp file I call this in jscript

```
window.showModalDialog(strPopUpUrl + "?URI=" + iURI, lObjArg, "dialogWidth:400px;dialogHeight:300px;center:1;help:0;resizable:0;status:0;");
```

lObjArg is object type. In one properties of this is written in false;

I another asp file that is called when modal dialog is opened I don't receive any parameter or value.

What can be solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is passed in [dialogAguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, but dialogArguments is always null regardless what I send.

Comment: I click on button in my mail. The button call one asp page (mypage.asp). Script in mypage.asp call ShowModalDialog. In the dialog Link to open is Tridion( CMS) asp page(tridion.asp) which always get null when try to read from window.dialogArguments.customArguments.

Comment: I solved this When modal dialog is called from Tridion it fill customArguments. But when it is called outside customArguments is always null. So on if statement solved this solution.

Comment: @PremsComp Great. Sorry I was offline